# UINavigationController embedded within tabBarController

Tags: iphone

have any example or code can show how to embedded a UINavigationController within tabBarController,typically we develop application is from UINavigationController rather than tabBarController,so i am so confuse now can help

Answer (score 1):

search on google tabbarcontroller+navigation controller.There are many tutorial on net

here is one tutorial for you
[TabbarController+NavigationController](http://twilloapp.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-embed-navigation-controller.html)